# RLIKE REGEX - Return given value without matching the spaces

Tags: php, mysql, regex, search, rlike

I am trying to make a simple regex expression for a master search in my MYSQL query.

All I want to do is return a match even if the value has spaces in it and my search value does not.

E.G.

If the user enters 'JoeBlogs' and I try to match this against the clients full name I wish the client to be returned even if there is a space between joe and blogs. Joe Blogs

Did not want to use REPLACE in my where clause as I know this can be quite expensive.

Currently just looking for exact matches like so.

```
WHERE client_name RLIKE '^joeblogs'
```

I assume this would be quite simple with regular expressions but have not yet got around to learning regex's

Thank you

Comment: How you gonna down vote a question. This is the best way i see apart from string functions and data normalisation

Comment: Your question is ""Can you write some code for me?""

Comment: Well not quite write code for me. more show me a possible way that regex can ignore white spaces or let me know if this is stupid not exactly asking for a script more like help with a few characters. Unless I am seriously under estimating the complexities of writing a regular expression I wouldn't imagine the it would be more than a few characters

Comment: OK, guess it gonna be normalisation then. Was pretty sure that stack overflow was to ask about code questions when your unsure how to implement yourself but hey thanks for all the help community

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP 'Joe ?Briggs'
```

The question mark says that the char before it is optional.

If you need it "anchored":

```
REGEXP '^Joe ?Briggs$'
```

Now nothing can exist before or after the name.  That is, "Joe Briggsworth" will not match.

For finding the name in the middle of a string *and* at word boundaries:

```
REGEXP '[[:<:]]Joe ?Briggs[[:>:]]'
```